# Python3 package file cannot import from same directory when used in a different directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, package, python-import

My directory structure is as follows

```
├── main.py
└── mypkg
    ├── barlib.py
    ├── foolib.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── pmain.py
```

I have two files that I want to run. `main.py` in parent directory and `pmain.py` in my package directory. I have a simple function `foo()` in `foolib.py`. In `barlib.py`, I import `foo` from `foolib`

```
from foolib import foo

def bar():
  foo()
```

In `pmain.py`, I import `bar` and use it. **So far so good. No errors.**

```
import barlib

barlib.bar()
```

Now in `main.py` in the parent directory, I want to use `bar` from `barlib`

```
from mypkg.barlib import bar

bar()
```

In **python 3** (tested with 3.6 and 3.8) this says that `barlib` cannot find `foolib` (But **python 2** gives me no error)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mypkg.barlib import bar
  File "/xxxxx/mypkg/barlib.py", line 1, in <module>
    from foolib import foo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foolib'
```

I can modify the import statement in `barlib` to import with the module name so that the error goes away

```
from mypkg.foolib import foo
```

But now I cannot run my other file `pmain` which is inside the package directory (obviously). It gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mypkg/pmain.py", line 1, in <module>
    from barlib import bar
  File "/xxxxx/mypkg/barlib.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mypkg.foolib import foo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypkg'
```

Can someone please explain what's happening here? I could not find another similar question on this behavior of python3

**How do I import inside the package directory so that I can use `bar` in both the parent and package directory?**

---

EDIT: [Here's a script](https://gist.github.com/teshanshanuka/2d5775d163c9bce784abc9b88cedf7b0) to recreate the folder structure if anybody wants to reproduce the problem

Comment: what is inside your `__init__.py`?

Comment: Nothing. Its there just to make `mypkg` a package

Comment: Did it worked? Let me know else I will remove the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to import functions outside `mypkg`, you can try this way:

Step 1: Edit your `__init__.py`

```
from .foolib import foo
from .barlib import bar
```

Step2: Add import of `mypkg` in `main.py`

```
import mypkg
```

Step3: Now, you can use `foo` and `bar` in `main.py` like this:

```
mypkg.foo()

mypkg.bar()
```

After making a similar structure locally, It worked out for me for both Python2 and Python3. Can you check again?

My file structure looks like:

- pyprob

  - `main.py`
  - mypkg

    - `__init__.py`
    - `barlib.py`
    - `foolib.py`
    - `pmain.py`

The contents of files are:

- `__init__.py`

  ```
  from .barlib import *
  from .foolib import *
  ```
- `barlib.py`

  ```
  from .foolib import foo

  print("We are in barlib")

  def bar():
     print("Calling foo()")
     foo()
  ```
- `foolib.py`

  ```
  def foo():
    print("We are in foo() now")
  ```
- `pmain.py`

  ```
  from .barlib import bar

  print("We are in pmain")
  bar()
  ```
- `main.py`

  ```
  print("We are in main.py")

  import mypkg

  mypkg.bar()
  ```

-> Run the `main.py` in Python2 or Python3

- `python2 main.py` or `python3 main.py`

-> Run the `pmain.py` in `mypkg` package in Python2 or Python3

- `python2 -m mypkg.pmain` or `python3 -m mypkg.pmain`.

The commands are like these because `mypkg` is a package.

-> Output

- ```
  We are in main.py
  We are in barlib
  Calling foo()
  We are in foo() now
  ```

Comment: This did not work. Still `barlib` cannot find `foolib`

Comment: If you're still interested, you can create my folder structure from [this script](https://gist.github.com/teshanshanuka/2d5775d163c9bce784abc9b88cedf7b0) and check for yourself

Comment: Did you try running `pmain.py` ?. `File "mypkg/pmain.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .barlib import bar
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.barlib'; '__main__' is not a package` This exactly is my problem. I cannot create the files do that I can run both `main` and `pmain`

Comment: Add the command you want to run in question and I will try them out and let you know soon.

Comment: Both `python3 main.py` and `python3 mypkg/pmain.py`

Comment: Updated the answer. Can you check now?